# Phone Number and Job Titile from Google User Account via OAUTH2

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

I use google oauth2 to authorize users in my spring app. I can retrieve first and last name, email. But I also need to get their phone number and profession (jobTitle). How to retrieve phone number and profession from profile about me?

I used all scopes in application.yml- openid, email, profile, address, phone. There is no information in the `(DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal()` object that I need. Maybe I need to use Google People API for it?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [Example]

Answer (score 0):

If you are already getting the names and email then all you need to do is add occupation and birthday to the personFields property its a coma separated field so the following should do it.

```
names,occupations,birthdays,email
```

The issue will probably be the scopes you are requesting. You will probably need to add.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read